# Is it possible to save on database without a PXGraph or a Screen?

Tags: acumatica

The entry for that screen is not needed. All the records are automatically generated. or probably by using DAC only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Graph/DAC logic is preferred as you get all of the framework freebies such as field defaulting and calculated formula fields.

You can however get around this using `PXDatabase.Insert` or `PXDatabase.Update` `PXDatabase.Delete`

I use these for upgrade processes or bulk delete of processing records. These calls do not require a graph to execute but ignore all DAC attributes which may or may not default values, calculate values, etc.

If you search on PXDatabase in the Acumatica code browser you can find examples. Here is one from `EmployeeMaint.Location_RowPersisted`:

```
PXDatabase.Update<Location>(
    new PXDataFieldAssign("VAPAccountLocationID", _KeyToAbort),
    new PXDataFieldRestrict("LocationID", _KeyToAbort),
    PXDataFieldRestrict.OperationSwitchAllowed);
```

PXDataFieldAssign is setting column values.
PXDataFieldRestrict is your where condition.

It is best to find multiple examples of PXDatabase in Acumatica and confirm your query results using a tool such as SQL profiler to make sure its executing the correct statement you intend to run.

Comment: thanks! I found my solution, I used PXGraph without building another screen, so I insert my data just by using PXGraph paired with a DAC.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **DAC** without **Graph**. All **BQL** queries require **PXGraph** instance. The only way to save data without using **BQL** is using **ODBC** or any other **ORM** to connect strictly to database and do your changes. But it is not recommended way as in case of doing it in that way you will ignore all the Business Logic.